# how do i add a 3d object into my website?

Tags: web, 3d, aframe

I have a google sites website with embedded 3D objects, how do I get a OBJ file into the embed on the website ?
the code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.1.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a-scene>


            <a-sphere position="0 -5 -24" radius="5" color="purple"></a-sphere>
            
            <a-sphere position="0 -5 -10" radius="4" color="green"></a-sphere>
            <a-sphere position="0 -5 -0" radius="3" color="red"></a-sphere>
            <a-sphere position="0 -5 10" radius="2" color="yellow"></a-sphere>
            <a-sphere position="0 -5 20" radius="1" color="blue"></a-sphere>
            
        </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is the site to see: https://sites.google.com/view/aircraftrecognitionuk/home , I want an airplane instead of the spheres, plz can someone edit this code for me, TIA

the file name is:

plane.obj

alternately if someone would like to help edit it on the site then plz message me and I can add u to help on the google site

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `.obj` model with the [obj-model](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/obj-model.html#sidebar) component:

```
<a-scene>
  <!-- Preload with a-assets -->
  <a-assets>
    <a-asset-item id="model-obj" src="/path/to/model.obj"></a-asset-item>
    <a-asset-item id="model-mtl" src="/path/to/model.mtl"></a-asset-item>
  </a-assets>

  <!-- add the model to the scene -->
  <a-entity obj-model="obj: #model-obj; mtl: #model-mtl"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

---

Preferably You should use gltf models, and add them to the scene with the [gltf-model](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/gltf-model.html#sidebar) component.